# How can I make Emacs warn about calls to my pure functions?

Tags: byte-compilation, warning

Emacs' byte-compiler can tell me if I call pure functions without saving the result:

```el
(defun foo-calls-add ()
  ;; value returned from (+ 1 2) is unused:
  (+ 1 2)
  12)
```

However, I don't get any warnings when I define my own pure functions:

```el
(defun foo-pure (x)
  (declare (pure t) (side-effect-free error-free))
  x)

(defun foo-calls-pure ()
  ;; No warning here:
  (foo-pure 1)
  12)
```

What do I need to do in order for the byte compiler to warn about `foo-calls-pure`?

I've compared `(symbol-plist '+)` with `(symbol-plist 'foo-pure)` and I can't see any obvious missing properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in `byte-optimize-form-code-walker`, you can see that a warning is printed for side-effect-free functions, but error-free functions just get optimized out and logged (not warned) only.  Logging means it only shows up if have `byte-optimize-log` set to non-nil (you'll want to set it to `source` otherwise there's a lot of noise).

```el
      ((and for-effect (setq tmp (get fn 'side-effect-free))
            (or byte-compile-delete-errors
                (eq tmp 'error-free)
                (progn
                  (byte-compile-warn "value returned from %s is unused"
                                     (prin1-to-string form))
                  nil)))
       (byte-compile-log "  %s called for effect; deleted" fn)
       ;; appending a nil here might not be necessary, but it can't hurt.
       (byte-optimize-form
        (cons 'progn (append (cdr form) '(nil))) t)
```

Additionally, the declaration doesn't take effect during compilation unless you use `eval-when-compile`, so you'll need something like:

```el
(eval-and-compile
  (defun foo-pure (x)
    (declare (pure t) (side-effect-free t))
    x))
```

Or to avoid putting the whole `defun` inside `eval-and-compile`:

```el
(eval-and-compile (function-put 'foo-pure 'side-effect-free 't))
```

Comment: "the declaration doesn't take effect during compilation", aha, that's a subtlety that I completely missed. Is this documented, or did you just look at the code?

Comment: Actually I just guessed & checked that one. It doesn't seem like great behaviour, perhaps worth a bug report to change the `declare` expansion to use `eval-and-compile`.

Comment: Awesome, so that works nicely. If `foo-pure` is in a separate library that's byte-compiled, then downstream consumers will get the error without me doing `function-put`.

Comment: I've [opened an Emacs bug too](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24863). I've proposed a patch but changing `defun-declarations-alist` in my current Emacs instance doesn't fix the issue.